# Playstore: I can't create subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I'm just trying to create a subscription. If you read the [oficial documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-new-subscription) you will see:

Open Play Console and go to the Subscriptions page (Monetize > Products > Subscriptions).
Click **Create subscription**.

The problem is that I don't have the label. I only have a button to upload a APK.

[image: Playstore create subscription]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem... it turns out that *before* you can set up a subscription, your app needs to have the `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` permission in your manifest file. You can get that in there one of two ways: either by manually adding it, or by simply adding a library dependency to `implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.1.0"` (or whatever the latest version is) to your build file, rebuilding, and re-upload. Once Play console sees the billing permission on your APK, it will allow you to create a subscription (assuming you also have a merchant account setup correctly).

Comment: It took me way too long to find this solution

Comment: @robert-c-barth Extremely helpful, got me unblocked on an Expo project to [get the billing client](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#groovy) implemented using the [`withDangerousMond`](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/#experimental-functionality) approach.

Comment: @Robert C. Barth once I added the permission to the manifest file, should I upload it to the internal testing? or it must be at least closed testing?